# Android Ormlite mapping to Sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I can't find the Ormlite DataType mapping for Android to Sqlite.  I've found [OrmLite SQL Data Types](http://ormlite.com/data_types.shtml) but the Sqlite column is blank.  Anyone know were I can find them?

I need them to update my database schema ie:

```
  meetingDao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE meeting ADD closed ????");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking but Sqlite is a type-less database.  Everything is stored as a string basically with certain functions allowing numerical, time, etc. calculations at runtime on those strings.

To quote from the [Sqlite data-type docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html):

> SQLite is "typeless". This means that you can store any kind of data you want in any column of any table, regardless of the declared datatype of that column. (See the one exception to this rule in section 2.0 below.) This behavior is a feature, not a bug. A database is suppose to store and retrieve data and it should not matter to the database what format that data is in. The strong typing system found in most other SQL engines and codified in the SQL language spec is a misfeature - it is an example of the implementation showing through into the interface. SQLite seeks to overcome this misfeature by allowing you to store any kind of data into any kind of column and by allowing flexibility in the specification of datatypes.

In the SQL Data Types page you mentioned, the Sqlite column is blank because it uses the base data columns without the need to override them.  Even if I changed the base types for a class, Sqlite will not override any of the types because, again, it is a type-less database.

Comment: Thanks Gray.  So when upgrading the Android sqlite database I don't have to match the data entity classes ie. @DatabaseField private int count; DateType INTERGER doesn't need the DataType defined in the ALTER statement.   meetingDao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE meeting ADD count"); is all that is required.  I ask this because the documentation suggests that ormlite itself does define Data types. ie. CREATE TABLE `orders`
   (`id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT , `account_id` INTEGER...

Comment: The `AUTO_INCREMENT` is necessary for the ids to be assigned.  The field types however are not used at all and does not need to match.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the mapping table linked by the original question: [OrmLite SQL Data Types](http://ormlite.com/data_types.shtml) shows the correct types that ORMLite is using, although it only shows differences for each database from the **Base Database** column. For example a Java `long` is created as a column with the `BIGINT` type.

While SQLite3 doesn't have types, it has the concept of [type affinities](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) which ORMLite uses when creating the table.

You should probably include the types in database upgrades as well, or you'll get a different table definition when ORMLite is automatically creating the table form scratch and when you upgrade.